# Does snprintf clobber the buffer after null-terminator?

Tags: c++, c, string, printf

Consider the following code:

```
char buffer[5]{};
snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "hi");
```

`snprintf` writes `'h'`, `'i'` and `'\0'` to `buffer`.

My question is: is there any guarantee that the `snprintf` won't touch `buffer[3]` and `buffer[4]` according to the standard? Visual Studio 2019 keeps the unused buffer untouched, but is this a standard behavior?

Comment: Of course there's no such guarantee. `snprintf` may user the whole buffer for its needs. This is a C runtime function. Why is the question tagged with C++?

Comment: @273K edited. Is there a safe function that does not clobber the buffer?

Comment: Note that `char buffer[5]{};` is not valid C — not even in C23, AFAIK.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler It seems to be valid in C++.

Comment: At the time I commented, the question was not tagged with C++ — so the validity of the construct in C++ was not an issue.  The question is back to being tagged with C and C++ — this is not an improvement.  Choose which language you're interested in and show code that's valid in that language.  Don't try asking about both languages — the answer is probably different.

Comment: It smells the XY-problem. Why do you need this strange requirement? You gave N bytes to a function, why do you want to expect that it does not touch some of tail bytes? What the actual problem are you solving?

Comment: XY problem or not, there is an answer to this question, and the answer is basically "if you can find an explicit guarantee in the `sprintf()` man page, then the behavior is guaranteed; OTOH if you can't find it mentioned in the man page, then you shouldn't rely on it".  (even if you test and find that current implementations do what you want, it's possible that next year's code updates may implement some some fun new optimization that breaks your code because you assumed a behavior that wasn't documented to be present)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner If you can't rely on a function not to modify memory contents its documentation doesn't say it will modify, you can't really write code at all.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz agreed, but in this case the docs all seem to say something along the lines of "snprintf(n, ....) will write to up to (n-1) bytes in the buffer"; they don't say anything about a guarantee that they will necessarily write *fewer* than (n-1) bytes.  So you could assume that they will only write a smaller number based on the format string you passed in, but that would be an assumption and the snprintf() implementers would be within their rights (AFAICT) if they didn't abide by it.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner Does the documentation say it *will* modify those bytes? No, it does not. And, as I said, "*If you can't rely on a function not to modify memory contents its documentation doesn't say it will modify, you can't really write code at all.*" What would it write to them? Random stuff? You don't need a specific guarantee a function won't modify memory its specification doesn't say it will modify. A function can't change stuff you can see that its spec doesn't say it'll change.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I can certainly imagine an implementation that clears those bytes.  The spec says it will "write up to (n-1) bytes", so I take it at face value rather than inferring unstated rules about exactly how many bytes it will actually write.

Comment: @JeremyFriesner I don't know where you're getting that from but neither [POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/snprintf.html) nor [ISO/IEC](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) say that. And, in any event, I think it would be crazy to argue that this means it can write whatever it wants to those bytes.

Answer (score 2):

The [N1548](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1548.pdf) draft ISO/IEC 9899:201x Programming languages — C

> **7.21.6.5 The `snprintf` function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> 1. ```
>    #include <stdio.h>
>    int snprintf(char * restrict s, size_t n,
>         const char * restrict format, ...);
>    ```
>
> **Description**
>
> 2. The **`snprintf`** function is equivalent to **`fprintf`**, except that the output is written into an array (specified by argument **`s`**) rather than to a stream. If **`n`** is zero, nothing is written, and **`s`** may be a null pointer. Otherwise, output characters beyond the **`n-1`**st are discarded rather than being written to the array, and a null character is written at the end of the characters actually written into the array. If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>
> **Returns**
>
> 3. The **`snprintf`** function returns the number of characters that would have been written had **`n`** been sufficiently large, not counting the terminating null character, or a negative value if an encoding error occurred. Thus, the null-terminated output has been completely written if and only if the returned value is nonnegative and less than **`n`**.

It clearly defines how much characters would be written. It does not guarantee that characters are not modified in the target buffer after the returned value + 1.

If you run your code in POSIX environment and if such the guarantee is a requirement, you can use a memory stream opened with `fmemopen()` and used with `fprintf()`. `fprintf()` guarantees that it will not modify characters after the terminating null character.

```
char buffer[5]{};
FILE* f = fmemopen(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "w");
fprintf(f, "hi");
fclose(f);
```

Comment: Isn't `fmemopen` POSIX function, and thus not available in Visual Studio?

Comment: You don't need a written guarantee that functions won't modify things their description doesn't say they'll modify. If you did, every single function would have to contain such guarantees or you couldn't code at all. You can absolutely rely on a function not modifying observable values without the documentation warning you that it will change those values.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I share the same opinion with you. As it is pointed out in this answer, the behaviour is equivalent to `fprintf` and a file function would not write extra tailing bytes and ruin the file buffer.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot think of a reason that it will alter content in the remaining space. But if you are worried about that, determine the length before calling snprintf() in the code like below.

```
int main() {
    char buffer[5]{};
    char p[] = "hi";
    size_t len = strlen(p);
    size_t num = len < sizeof(buffer) ? len + 1 : sizeof(buffer);
    snprintf(buffer, num, p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think the code in the question is a simplified example. OP could just use `strncpy`. Actually, "hi" can be a format string and you can't know the resulting length until you call `snprintf()`.

Comment: strncpy() doesn't involve destination buffer size. If it's a format string in snprintf(), write to a spare buffer which has no worrying about the remaining space. "char buffer[5]" is just a concept of buffer containing useful data.

Comment: @273K Yes. If it is a format string, `snprintf` needs to be called twice to get real string size at first, and then do actual print.